# How can we monitor mongoDB queries?

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb, mongoose

I just wanted to know if there is a possible way to monitor mongoDB queries.
I tried with the explain functionality provided by the mongo shell. But it is very hectic to manually track each and every query. 
I am using mongoose as an ODM.

The one which I tried is:

```
db.customer.find({},{name:1, active:1}).explain()
```

I got an object with the query plan, time taken and many more things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongoose out-of-the-box supports only basic debug:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

But that doesn't measure query time so is almost no use for profiling. Since mongoose 4.* you can use middleware to measure request time:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

There are some nodejs libs to measure execution time of different code blocks and app performance:

- http://www.devmetrics.io/logs?section=performance
- http://benchmarkjs.com
- ...

Answer (score 5):

The number of read (query, getmore) and write (insert, delete, update) operations are reported in [*opcounters*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#opcounters) under the *serverStatus* command.
Remember that you should also correlate these throughput statistics along with resource saturation metrics such as `currentQueue.readers` and `currentQueue.writers` (also part of *serverStatus*).

[Here](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/collecting-mongodb-metrics-and-statistics/) are detailed all the different ways to collect the metrics you need: using Utilities, Commands, or monitoring tools integrating with MongoDB (in the same series you will also find all the statistics you need to properly monitor MongoDB).

Answer (score 3):

What you need is [debugging mode](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#enable_debugging):

> All executed collection methods will log output of their arguments to your console

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

Or you could add callback as third argument that allows you get additional info:

```
mongoose.set('debug', function (collection, method, query, doc [, options]) {
    console.log(/* your log format */);
});
```

MongoDB also provides monitoring of your mongod server in a cloud with [MMS](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/).

**EDIT:** to save your queries in csv you could use [csv-write-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream) module with the following example:

```
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var writer = csvWriter();

// create write stream to `queries.csv` file.
writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('queries.csv'));

mongoose.set('debug', function (collection, method, query, doc [, options]) {
    writer.write({collection: collection, method: method, query: query, doc: JSON.stringify(doc)});   
});

// close stream on mongoose disconnected
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {  
    writer.end();
});
```

Comment: I want it in a format so that I can analyze it later, like csv.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way of doing this by using [mongoDB profiler](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/). It writes the profile result into a collection called `system.profile` which can be queried as other collections and can be exported too.

There are two ways of enabling profiler:

1. Enable profiler for all the databases at once
2. Enable profiler for a particular database.

The following profiling levels are available:

> 0: No profiling, 1:profile slow operations and 3:profile all operation

See: [db.setProfilingLevel(2)](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#enable-database-profiling-and-set-the-profiling-level) and [db.getProfilingStatus()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#check-profiling-level)

Answer (score 1):

Use `db.setProfilingLevel()` to log slow queries or all queries. Then, use ElasticSearch + Kibana + Logstash to analyze and monitor mongoDB queries.